# How to implement a drop-down button inside a table header in Ext.js

Tags: javascript, extjs

For a month I have started working with Ext.Js 4, creating all kind of widgets. Right now I am tying to implement a drop-down option for a column header.

That can be based on something like this ColorPicker 
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.menu.ColorPicker

My code creates a Grid Panel like in this img

[image]

```
Ext.apply(me, {
    items : [{
        xtype : 'gridpanel',
        itemId : 'gridpanelId',
        margin : '0 0 0 0',
        layout : 'fit',
        viewConfig : {
            emptyText : '',
            deferEmptyText : false,
            markDirty : false
        },
            ftype : 'filters'
    }],
    store : errorstore,
    plugins : [Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
    pluginId : 'celledit',
    clicksToEdit : 1
    })],
    tbar : [{
        xtype : 'ixbutton',
        itemId : 'tbarswitcha',
        text : '',
        bgCls : 'but-image-base tbar_error_quit',
        height : 60,
        width : 90,
        margin : '0 10 0 10'
    }],
    columns : [{
        header : 'Startdate',
        itemId : 'ColumnStartdate',
        dataIndex : 'startdate',
        flex : 2,
        sortable : true,
        renderer : function(value) {
            return MyApp.app.formatDate(value);
                }
        },{
        header : 'Source',
        itemId : 'ColumnSource',
        dataIndex : 'source',
        flex : 3,
        sortable : false
        }
    ],
    bbar : {
        xtype : 'ixpagingtoolbar',
        itemId : 'ixpt',
        margin : '5 10 5 10',
        numbButtons : 4,
        width : 400
        }
    }]
});
```

I am trying to build a possibility for the user to choose a specific type of 'Source'. Something like a filter, where the user has pre-defined options from which to choose, and not to type in.

How should I define a drop-down inside this

```
columns : {
        header : 'Source'
}
```

Comment: why do you use Ext js

Comment: Because I am looking to implement a new functionality in an old system created in Ex.js... And I don´t have an option.. Do I !?`.

Comment: x) I'm doing the same stuff but that was so weird that i created a new page totally independent, i think no one can help you because its too old

Comment: check this out https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?149417-Combobox-in-header-column

Comment: Tnx @Jaydeep it is exactly what I am looking for, but I keep receiving ''Uncaught TypeError:  c is not a constructor '' ....

Comment: Have you included all the required classes in requires block?

Answer (score 0):

Any items you put in a column is placed in the header. Simple example without any styling:

```
columns = [
    {
        header: 'Source',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Options',
                menu: {
                    items: [
                        {
                            text: 'Item1'
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Item2'
                        },
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Comment: I am sorry if I haven´t made myself right understood but my porpoise is to have inside the `header : 'SOURCE'   `. an instead of just SOURCE to have also a drop-down button/arrow.